# XERGM R-package: GOF error with bipartite, temporal ERGM

Tags: r, networks

I was able to estimate the following temporal, bipartite ERGM using the `xergm` package in R:

```
require(xergm)
model1 <- btergm(observed_network ~ edges + b2star(2:3), R = 1000)
summary(model1)
```

When I try to estimate the goodness-of-fit (GOF) for the model using the `xergm` `gof` command, the following error appears:

```
gof(model1)

Error in MHproposal.formula(constraints, arguments = 
control$MCMC.prop.args,  : 
The combination of class (c), model constraints (), reference measure 
(Bernoulli), and proposal weighting (default) is not implemented. Check 
your arguments for typos.
```

My hunch is that the previous error relates to a problem with the way I 
specified the model for the goodness-of-fit. I used the `data.table` package to   construct the adjacency matrix, so it may be that `xergm` and `data.table` are not working well together.

Comment: Please supply the reproducible example. If the problem is really `data.table`, simply convert your `data.table` to `data.frame`. And read the site FAQ, if the question is about routine use of software, it does not belong on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into the same thing a while back. Make sure you've loaded both the statnet `library(statnet)`and xergm package `library(xergm)` and use the `gof` function of `xergm`, i.e. `xergm::gof()`.